# Does $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm reviewing improper integrals a bit and claim that$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}}$$

converges. First off all $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}}\leq\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{4/3}}$$

By the integral test ;  the integral on the right above converges if and only if the series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4/3}}$$
converges, which it does since it is a harmonic series with $p=4/3 > 1$. The original now converges by the comparison test. Is this sound? Also, how can analyze the value of this integral?

Comment: The only thing you can say with your test is that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}}\,\mathrm d x$ converges. You have now to stud the convergence of $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}}\,\mathrm d x$

Comment: I have never heard about this integral test. Let me know from where did you read about that and also $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{4/3}}$ diverges.

Comment: the harmonic series you mention converges if starting from $k=1$

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{4/3}}$ does not converge; it blows up at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to note
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p} dx \text{ converges }\iff p>1$$
and
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p} dx \text{ converges }\iff p<1$$

Therefore, the trick is to consider a bound for your function depending on where you integrate.
$$\text{consider } f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}} \text{ in }[0,1] \text{ and } [1,\infty]$$
In $[0,1]$ notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+x^2}} \leq x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ which makes the integral converge (since $p<1$) and for $[1,\infty]$ it converges due to the bound you mentioned ($f(x)\leq x^{-4/3}$) since $p>1$

Answer (score 0):

Render $x=\exp(u)$, then the integral becomes

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\exp(u) du}{\sqrt[3]{\exp(4u)+\exp(2u)}}$

where the integrand is comparable with $\exp(-|u|/3)$ at both limits.